# How not to display files in modified in git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have followings in the .gitignore file

```
application/config/database.php
application/config/config.php
```

But when I run git status both files are under modified. Isn't that git should ignore these files? How should I do so that these files won't be displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.gitignore` only applies to files that are *not* in the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop tracking the file.  You can do it by

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

and then

```
git add .
```

and commit

```
git commit -m "message"
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the entries into the .gitignore file were likely made after the files were already under version control. There are more elegant ways to do this, but a simple way to correct the situation would be to temporarily remove those lines from the .gitignore. Then, copy the files out of the project directory and commit the seemingly deleted files. Add your ignores back, and commit. Now, finally, move your files back in - they should be ignored properly, now. Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

gitignore only stops new files from being tracked. If a file is already tracked, it will continue to be tracked, even if it matches the ignore pattern.